# How to trigger tooltip from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to trigger ngx-bootstrap Tooltip from javascript. Below code is working without any problem. Now I want to call show() function from javascript side manually.

Problem is I don't know what "bs-tooltip" is. Is it an id of element created by ngx-bootstrap. If so how can I get this element from javascript?

[Ngx-bootstrap Tooltip](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#triggers-manual)

```
<p>
  <span tooltip="Hello there! I was triggered manually"
        triggers="" #customTooltip="bs-tooltip">
  This text has attached tooltip
  </span>
</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="customTooltip.show()">
  Show
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="customTooltip.hide()">
  Hide
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="customTooltip.toggle()">
  Toggle
</button>
```

**EDIT:**

```
document.getElementById("bs-tooltip")  //returns null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `viewChild` to acces the `customTooltip` in your component's class:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent {
    @ViewChild('customTooltip') tooltip: ElementRef;
    onClick() {
        this.tooltip.show();
    }
}

<span #customTooltip="bs-tooltip" tooltip="Hello there! I was triggered manually" triggers="" > This text has attached tooltip</span>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine but I am getting "Property 'show' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'." error. Is there any way to handle this error?

Comment: Try to give a type to the tooltip element:
`import {TooltipDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';`
`@ViewChild('customTooltip') tooltip: TooltipDirective;`